# Sharing a memory-mapped file from disk between processes

Tags: c#, ipc, memory-mapped-files

I'm facing problems which seems trivial when using the memory mapping feature available in .NET to share a physical file (it exists on disk) between processes during their execution.

My goal is:

- I have a file on disk, let's say File.dat
- I have two separate processes (they may be spawned at the same time, but not necessarily)
- Whoever starts first should load the file into memory, then use it
  for operations. The other process checks whether the file is loaded
  upon startup, sees that it indeed is, so it simply proceeds to its
  tasks

Currently, I'm using the `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile` function. I've noticed, however, that there's way to check whether some other process has already loaded the file into memory. Trying to load this file from two processes at the same time gives a sharing access violation.

There's the `CreateOrOpen` function, but it's only available for non-persistent data which is not my case. I've imagined a Mutex-like API where the function would throw an exception upon an attempt to create multiple files with the same name or do something similar. Clearly this approach hasn't been adopted in this case, so what else can I use to accomplish my goal?

Comment: The other process which may have opened the file does not belong to you?  Is that correct?  I take it that's why you can't ask that application to open it with read sharing?

Comment: Other than the sharing issue (you need to use an overload of Create... that supports sharing), I don't get why an instance of the app needs to know if it's the first one. Can't it just open the memory map and get on with it? - it's not like you are sharing the actual memory map object among processes anyway, only the view of the file.

Comment: I think I get it now - the name attribute passed in the CreateFromFile function tells the system that I would like to use this and this memory file. If it already exists, I'm simply given back a handle to it and may enjoy the data. Is that correct?

Comment: That should be correct, yes.